# What's the limit of $(1+\frac{1}{8^n})^n$

Tags: calculus

What's the limit of $(1+\frac{1}{8^n})^n$? How do I find the answer for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you've tried, in part because an Answer might be best targeted at helping you over a misunderstanding (given the level at which you approach such a problem).

Comment: Of course we are assuming that n goes to infinity? Or perhaps negative infinity?

Comment: I tried the sandwich theorem and ratio test... Didn't manage to solve it with that method.

Comment: $$\left(1+\frac1{8^n}\right)^n=\left(\left(1+\frac1{8^n}\right)^{8^n}\right)^{\frac{8^n}{n}}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee typo

Comment: @Lost1, something wrong in parsing the comment as it shows fine in the answer preview

Comment: Try taking logarithms and using the (easy) bound $\ln(1+x)\leq x$.

Comment: @richard : Please tell us what you've tried _in your question_, not just in a comment.  You can edit your questions.

Comment: @StefanSmith You'll find it interesting to know that `[edit]` becomes "edit" with a link to editing: [edit].

Comment: @Lord_Farin : Thanks, I'll try that.  Some people think commenters should edit questions, but I think OP's should learn how to clearly state their questions.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$$
\pars{1 + {1 \over 8^{n}}}^{n}
=
\expo{n\ln\pars{1 + 8^{-n}}}
\sim
\expo{n/8^{n}} \to \color{#0000ff}{\large 1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the Binomial Theorem:

$$(1+8^{-n})^n=\sum_{k=0}^n 8^{-nk}\binom nk = 1 + 8^{-n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n 8^{-n(k-1)}\binom nk\right)$$

and the identity $\displaystyle\binom nk = \binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}k$ to estimate the parenthesized sum.

---

NB. Logarithms (as Steven Stadnicki suggests) provide an easier solution, but perhaps you don't have them available yet.

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to let $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{8^n}\right)^n$ and then notice that $\ln(L)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{8^n}\right)$. Because $\ln(\cdot)$ is a continuous function, we can do that.  Then, you might be able to solve it from there.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}  (1+\frac{1}{8^n})^n$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}((1+\frac{1}{8^n})^{8^n})^\frac{n}{8^n}$$

$$e^{lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{n}{8^n}} = e^0 = 1$$

Comment: What makes these competing convergences easier than those already present in the given problem?

Comment: Outer exponent (and variable of limit) is not quite right.  Compare @labbhattacharjee's comment.